# Mongoengine cyclic reference and reverse_delete_rule: mongoengine.errors.NotRegistered

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

The following code has a scheme and a tag, a scheme is a tree of tags.

```py
from mongoengine import *


class Scheme(Document):
    #_id = None  # provided by mongodb
    name = StringField(max_length=120, required=True)
    tags = ListField(ReferenceField('Tag', reverse_delete_rule=PULL))


class Tag(Document):
    name = StringField(max_length=120)
    annotation_scheme = ReferenceField('Scheme', reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE)
    subtags = ListField(ReferenceField('self', reverse_delete_rule=PULL))
    parent = ReferenceField('self', reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE)
```

the line
  `tags = ListField(ReferenceField('Tag', reverse_delete_rule=PULL))` causes the error:

```
mongoengine.errors.NotRegistered: `Tag` has not been registered in the document registry.
```

Note that if I remove `reverse_delete_rule=PULL` everything works fine.
How I can solve this and keep the correct cascading behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is **separating the delete rule for model that referenced the "unregistered" model** as explained in this [Github issue](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/1707)

The method to use is [register_delete_rule](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.Document.register_delete_rule)

> This method registers the delete rules to apply when removing this object.

In this case by removing `reverse_delete_rule=PULL` in the declaration of `Scheme` and adding this line after the declaration of `Tag`

```py
Tag.register_delete_rule(Scheme, "tags", PULL)
```